# Expand reputation change event when clicking date, not just arrow

Tags: feature-request, bug, profile-page, user-interface

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open the reputation on a profile ([Such as mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/202832/mooseman?tab=reputation&sort=post&tt=activity))
2. Click on the date *next to* the arrow.

The details aren't expanded, even though the `td` has `cursor:pointer`. If you click the arrow, the details are toggled as expected.

I think the `click` function should be bound to the parent `td` rather than the arrow `a`.

---

Note this issue still exists on the [Activity tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/202832/mooseman?tt=activity) since [Profile Page Makeover, Part 3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244238/202832) rolled out on Meta.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot @web-tiki